# Firebase deploy node modules issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, highcharts, node-modules

I'm having some trouble with using firebase functions. So I have this library that requires terms and conditions to be accepted when npm install is ran, you have to type `y`. This works fine when i run it locally but when its deployed to firebase functions it doesn't work... I can only assume it is rejecting or skipping the terms.

Documentation on the website states you can set a node environment variable to automatically accept the terms and conditions and skip the install prompt.

I have tried this but i cannot get it to work....

Does firebase functions reinstall node modules every time a function is deployed? or has it been cached and therefore is not even trying to accept the terms and conditions with the new environment variable (if it is is there a way to clear node modules).

Sorry if this was confusing, if anything needs clarifying please ask me and i will update my question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm somewhat unfamiliar with this way of deployment. You couldn't do something like `yes | npm install`?

Comment: Which module is causing you problems during deployment?  Is there an error message or log to share?

Comment: Hi Doug. The Node.js API library i am using is this https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server . There is a section on there about setting an environment variable `ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE`. I am pretty sure its this because i get an png image back thats states the library hasn't been configured correctly which i have read is because the T&C's haven't been accepted.

Comment: Hi @h11. Could you provide us with a full content of the error message?

Comment: hi @pawael_d . Here is the image i receive https://i.ibb.co/QH45TzW/highcharts-Error.png

Comment: What are you trying to do with this module in Cloud Functions?  The instructions say that you should install globally, then run it on the command line.  Neither of those things are supported by Cloud Functions.

Comment: Its not just a cli. Theres a node implementation at the bottom of the documentation. see the section "Using as a Node.js Module"

Comment: Ive tried to do the same thing but as an app engine service and I am getting the same problem :(